# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm getting this error: *Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services'*

when i call a method in a consoleApplication project from a ASP.NET web application project, i get this error.

i can't seem to find a solution and would like some help. any help is greatly appreciated.

cheers

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I am having the same problem. I can't download the package anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference. In your project, right click "References" and click "Add Reference" Then go here and add it to your project.

[image]

Comment: hi. i've allready tried that, and it's not possible. asp.net web application project for some reason doesn't have the assemblies tab in the reference manager.